# PowerShell ISE: Debug another power-shell script called from a power-shell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise, script-debugging

I wants to debug a power-shell script which is called from my Main power-shell script using `PowerShell ISE`. Below is the sample code of my Main script.

```
$myLog = "$scriptPath\BuildRelease\logs\LaLogs.log"

$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
Set-Location -Path $scriptPath
Set-Location -Path BuildRelease
$paramList = "-ArgumentList -username $Login"

if($Mode -eq "False"){
    Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-noexit','-File', 'Release.ps1', $paramList
}
```

Here, I'm trying to step into **Release.ps1** script using `ISE`.

I have tried to do this by pressing `F11` key, but instead of debugger going to this script, script gets executed (same as Step Over, instead of Step into).

Does anyone know how can I do this??

Comment: effin recursion... ;(

Comment: kidding apart, whats teh logic behind "Start-Process powershell"?

Comment: I'm executing the Release.ps1 script on another instance that's why I'm using Start-Process powershell. And this is something which customer wants me to do it like this way.

Comment: Debug how? You can run it manually if you know the conditions that make it fail as Nico has suggested. If you want to test it in a live environment as-is you'll need to set up proper error trapping that logs errors to a file or displays them on a popup or something. If you know the error but need to see variables that's another story. We need to know what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

by using `Start-Process` you run a new instance of powershell. So that why you can't debug your script.
You can call other script in you script by using :

`.\Release.ps1 -username $Login`

And with this, you can debbug your script

Comment: Is there any way to debug it with this way only (executing script in another instance)?

Comment: I don't think so, you can try to use the parameter : `NoNewWindow` but don't think it work. Else if you must debug your script without ./, you can add manually breaking point to your second script by using : `New-PsBreakpoint` .... Some useful links : [PowerShell Debugger](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730925.aspx) or [Quick and Efficient PowerShell Script Debugging](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2421573). I never use this kind of debbug

Comment: Thanks Nico , that's really help me to debug it as per my requirement.